# filtering on visualisation metrics in Kibana

Tags: json, elasticsearch, kibana-4

I'm trying to apply a filter to line visualisations in Kibana 4.5.1. I have an index (xscores) with two different types (sd and sma), here is a sample:

```
 {
        "_index": "xscore",
        "_type": "xscore",
        "_id": "AVgAejjHwGMH9TPDlF04",
        "_score": 1,
        "_source": {
           "id": "AVgAejjHwGMH9TPDlF04",
           "value": 0.019607843137254926,
           "timestamp": 1477476480000,
           "minutes": 1,
           "type": "sma"
        }
```

I am trying to show the **sum only for sma** and the **average only for sd** by adding a filter in the json box. However I always get a search_phase_execution_exception. This is the code that Kibana sends to elasticsearch:

```
  {"query": {
"filtered": {
  "query": {
    "query_string": {
      "analyze_wildcard": true,
      "query": "*"
    }
  },
  "filter": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "range": {
            "timestamp": {
              "gte": 1477436400000,
              "lte": 1477522799999,
              "format": "epoch_millis"
            }
          }
        }
      ],
      "must_not": [

      ]
    }
  }
}},"size": 0,"aggs": {
"3": {
  "date_histogram": {
    "field": "timestamp",
    "interval": "30m",
    "time_zone": "Europe\/London",
    "min_doc_count": 1,
    "extended_bounds": {
      "min": 1477436400000,
      "max": 1477522799999
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "4": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "type",
        "size": 5,
        "order": {
          "1": "desc"
        }
      },
      "aggs": {
        "1": {
          "avg": {
            "field": "value"
          }
        },
         "2": {
          "sum": {
            "field": "value",
            "filter": {
              "term": {
                "type": "sma"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}}}
```

The problem is in the last area I think but can't figure out what exactly is wrong.
Running the same query in ES returns the following error:

```
"shard": 0,
        "index": "xscore",
        "node": "mszD3Y_4T-aGNEkVtt4BCg",
        "reason": {
           "type": "search_parse_exception",
           "reason": "Unexpected token START_OBJECT in [2]."
```

I'm using ES 2.3 and Kibana 4.5 on a MacOS 10.10.

Comment: Are you running ES with cluster (multi nodes)

Comment: @BEJGAMSHIVAPRASAD no - hoping to keep it all within just the one node / index